# Webcam not working, but works on Windows

Tags: 20.04, windows, video, webcam

*Hello dear Ubuntu community*

My webcam is not working. On Windows 10 it works fine, no problems. lsusb shows no webcam. Cheese says there is an error.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am new to Ubuntu so my webcam has never worked, as far as I know.

This is a laptop, model ThinkPad X1 Tablet G2. It is an integrated webcam.

Output of ls -lah /dev/video*:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  0 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  1 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 16 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 17 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  2 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  3 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  8 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  9 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video5
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video6
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video7
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video8
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video9
```

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:60a3 Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Tablet Thin Keyboard Gen 2
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks a lot!